# nativescript-onesignal fails android build

Tags: nativescript, onesignal

I tried installing package nativescript-onesignal. After that, I got an error like UNMET PEER DEPENDANCY. Then I updated my modules following some posts on GitHub and StackOverflow. But, now when I try to build and run the application I got BUILD FAILED error. Unable to understand what went wrong. I followed some posts to resolve this but with no success.
Following is the error I got in the console.

```
tns run android
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-camera for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-carousel for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-drop-down for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-filter-select for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-geolocation for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-gradient for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-imagepicker for android.
nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager is not supported for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-loading-indicator for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-localstorage for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-locate-address for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-numeric-keyboard for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-onesignal for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-phone for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-social-share for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-telerik-ui for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-theme-core for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-webview-interface for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-i18n for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-permissions for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for android.
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Configuring > 0/3 projects > root project
 :config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles
> Configuring > 0/3 projects > root project
 :config phase:  addAarDependencies
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\Common-2017.1.719-dev-release.aar
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\Data-2017.1.719-dev-release.aar
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\List-2017.1.719-dev-release.aar
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\Primitives-2017.1.719-dev-release.aar
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\widgets-release.aar
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_2xnifqnj4smqh1ggt6ywlsjt4.run(C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\build-tools\android-static-binding-generator\build.gradle:144)
:asbg:clean UP-TO-DATE
:deleteMetadata
:deleteFlavors
:deleteConfigurations UP-TO-DATE
:deleteGeneratedBindings UP-TO-DATE
:clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 30.954 secs
Project successfully prepared (Android)
Building project...
> Configuring > 0/3 projects > root project
 :config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles
        +found plugins: nativescript-camera
         + creating include.gradle file for C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-camera
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\nativescript-camera -> C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F0
        +found plugins: nativescript-carousel
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\nativescript-carousel -> C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F1
        +found plugins: nativescript-geolocation
         + creating include.gradle file for C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-geolocation
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\nativescript-geolocation -> C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F2
        +found plugins: nativescript-imagepicker
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\nativescript-imagepicker -> C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F3
        +found plugins: nativescript-onesignal
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\nativescript-onesignal -> C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F4
        +found plugins: nativescript-phone
         + creating include.gradle file for C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-phone
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\nativescript-phone -> C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F5
        +found plugins: nativescript-telerik-ui
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\nativescript-telerik-ui -> C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F6
        +found plugins: nativescript-webview-interface
         + creating include.gradle file for C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-webview-interface
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\nativescript-webview-interface -> C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F7
        +found plugins: tns-core-modules-widgets
         + creating include.gradle file for C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\tns-core-modules-widgets
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\tns-core-modules-widgets -> C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F8
> Configuring > 0/3 projects > root project
:config phase:  createPluginsConfigFile
         Creating product flavors include.gradle file in C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android/configurations folder...

:config phase:  pluginExtend
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-camera\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-carousel\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-geolocation\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-imagepicker\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-onesignal\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-phone\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-telerik-ui\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-webview-interface\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\configurations\tns-core-modules-widgets\include.gradle
> Configuring > 0/3 projects > root project
 :config phase:  addAarDependencies
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\Common-2017.1.719-dev-release.aar
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\Data-2017.1.719-dev-release.aar
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\List-2017.1.719-dev-release.aar
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\Primitives-2017.1.719-dev-release.aar
        +adding dependency: C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\libs\aar\widgets-release.aar
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_2xnifqnj4smqh1ggt6ywlsjt4.run(C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\build-tools\android-static-binding-generator\build.gradle:144)
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugManifest
:preF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAquaappRuntimeUnspecifiedLibrary
:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2600Alpha1Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1104Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1104Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1104Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1104Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1104Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1104Library
:prepareComOnesignalOneSignal362Library
:prepareComRomandanylykPageindicatorview020Library
:prepareCommon20171719DevReleaseLibrary
:prepareData20171719DevReleaseLibrary
:prepareList20171719DevReleaseLibrary
:preparePrimitives20171719DevReleaseLibrary
:prepareWidgetsReleaseLibrary
:prepareF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugDependencies
:compileF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugAidl
:compileF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugRenderscript
:generateF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugBuildConfig
:cleanLocalAarFiles
:ensureMetadataOutDir
:collectAllJars
:setProperties
:generateTypescriptDefinitions SKIPPED
:copyTypings SKIPPED
:asbg:generateInterfaceNamesList
:asbg:traverseJsFiles
:asbg:runAstParser
Running full build
finished with reading lines with js files
:asbg:generateBindings
:generateF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugResValues
:generateF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugResources
:mergeF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugResources
:processF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugManifest
[com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.2] C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.onesignal\OneSignal\3.6.2\AndroidManifest.xml:52:13-48 Error:
   Attribute meta-data#onesignal_app_id@value at [com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.2] AndroidManifest.xml:52:13-48 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_app_id> is provided.
[com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.2] C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.onesignal\OneSignal\3.6.2\AndroidManifest.xml:56:13-67 Error:
   Attribute meta-data#onesignal_google_project_number@value at [com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.2] AndroidManifest.xml:56:13-67 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_google_project_number> is provided.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F0\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Attribute meta-data#onesignal_app_id@value at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_app_id> is provided.
C:\Users\Rajdeep\Documents\aqua-app\src\platforms\android\src\F0\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Attribute meta-data#onesignal_google_project_number@value at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_google_project_number> is provided.
> Building 67% > :processF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugManifest
See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

:processF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8DebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 7.429 secs
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.
```

Please help me solve this.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your Gradle build:

`Attribute meta-data#onesignal_app_id@value at [com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.2] AndroidManifest.xml:52:13-48 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_app_id> is provided.`

`Attribute meta-data#onesignal_google_project_number@value at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_google_project_number> is provided.`

According to the onesignal documentation, you need to provide both of these in order to use the plugin - https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

So, you could include, in your app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle the following:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "PUT YOUR ONESIGNAL APP ID HERE",
                              // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                              onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please help me how to handle notifications in the app(javascript).

Comment: You'll have to refer to the nativescript plugin documentation for that, and if there is none, check out the onesignal android and iOS plugin docs, then call their classes and methods in javascript. You could also post an issue in the plugin's github repo.

Comment: Yes. But, I can't find documentation which is for `javascript` especially `NativeScript`. Please help me.

Comment: Noop, still getting the error https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/639#issuecomment-494756894